# Can I put the contents of my SMS inbox into an array?

Tags: android, listview, sms

**This pertains to a listview with two textviews. The first textview lists the contacts, while the second textview is suppose to display the number of messages in the inbox FROM the respecting contact(s).**

I have been able to count the number of messages in my inbox on my device by parsing

```
String inbox = "content://sms/inbox"
```

into a string. But I want to go deeper than just getting a lump sum. is it possible to go deeper into the inbox and separate the total number of messages to their corresponding contacts? An example would be if I have 3 contacts and a lump sum of 20 messages, contact1 has 11 messages, contact2 has 4 messages, and contact3 has 6 messages.

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of how many texts in your inbox from each sender, you can use a SQL Group By clause. This is the popular trick to sneak a Group By clause into a ContentProvider:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
        Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/"),
        new String[] { "_id", "address", "count(*) as totals" },
        "1) Group By (address",
        null,
        null);
```

However this does not work for Android 4.0+. (For me designing ContentProviders without a Group By clause is like manufacturing a keyboard without numbers...)  For 4.0+, I would suggest iterating through the regular cursor and sorting the messages yourself.